# ViewHolder with a constructor which takes a view recycler view

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, fastadapter

Hi Friends i had struck in this problem from 2 days i dont know whats the problem here i am using the Fast `Adapter` by mikepenz where i have two recycler view in this.Here i am getting this error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: You have to provide a ViewHolder with a constructor which takes a view!
at com.mikepenz.fastadapter.items.AbstractItem$ReflectionBasedViewHolderFactory.create(AbstractItem.java:349)
```

I think i had set the everything correct as i am using same format in other class as well but i am only facing this issue class only and i dont have activated the progurard please find the below code

Main Class:

```
public class Incoming_request extends Fragment {
@BindView(R.id.incoming_req_recycler_view)
RecyclerView incoming_req_recycler_view;
@BindView(R.id.people_recycler_view)
RecyclerView people_recycler_view;
FastItemAdapter<Incoming_Request_adapter> incoming_req_adapter = new FastItemAdapter<>();
FastItemAdapter<People_Request_adapter> people_req_adapter = new FastItemAdapter<>();
@BindView(R.id.frd_req_no)
AppCompatTextView frd_req_no;
  @BindView(R.id.namesearch)
AutoCompleteTextView namesearch;
ArrayList<Search_Pojo> searchlist = new ArrayList<>();
Search_Adapter search_adapter;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.incoming_req, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    incoming_req_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    people_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    incoming_requests("");
    incoming_req_recycler_view.setAdapter(incoming_req_adapter);
    people_recycler_view.setAdapter(people_req_adapter);
    search_adapter=new Search_Adapter(getActivity(),R.layout.search_adapter_item,searchlist);
    namesearch.setThreshold(1);
    namesearch.setAdapter(search_adapter);
    search_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    namesearch.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Search_Pojo search = (Search_Pojo) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            namesearch.setText(search.getUsername());
            Intent otherprofileintent = new Intent(getActivity(), Other_Profile.class);
            otherprofileintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            otherprofileintent.putExtra("frd_status", search.getFriend_status());
            otherprofileintent.putExtra("frd_id", search.getUserid());
            startActivity(otherprofileintent);
        }
    });
    people_req_adapter.withOnClickListener(new FastAdapter.OnClickListener<People_Request_adapter>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClick(View v, IAdapter<People_Request_adapter> adapter, People_Request_adapter item, int position) {
            Intent otherprofileintent = new Intent(getActivity(), Other_Profile.class);
            otherprofileintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            otherprofileintent.putExtra("frd_status", item.getFriend_status());
            otherprofileintent.putExtra("frd_id", item.getTo_user_id());
            startActivity(otherprofileintent);
            return true;
        }
    });
    people_req_adapter.withItemEvent(new ClickEventHook<People_Request_adapter>() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v, int position, FastAdapter<People_Request_adapter> fastAdapter, People_Request_adapter item) {
            acceptrequest(item.getTo_user_id(), position);
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onBind(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
            if (viewHolder instanceof Incoming_Request_adapter.FriendRequest_ViewHolder) {
                return viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.accept);
            }
            return null;
        }
    });
    people_req_adapter.withItemEvent(new ClickEventHook<People_Request_adapter>() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v, int position, FastAdapter<People_Request_adapter> fastAdapter, People_Request_adapter item) {
            deleterequest(item.getTo_user_id(), position);
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onBind(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
            if (viewHolder instanceof Incoming_Request_adapter.FriendRequest_ViewHolder) {
                return viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
            }
            return null;
        }
    });
    people_req_adapter.withItemEvent(new ClickEventHook<People_Request_adapter>() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v, int position, FastAdapter<People_Request_adapter> fastAdapter, People_Request_adapter item) {
            sendrequest(item.getTo_user_id(), position);
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onBind(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
            if (viewHolder instanceof Incoming_Request_adapter.FriendRequest_ViewHolder) {
                return viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.sendrequest);
            }
            return null;
        }
    });

    incoming_req_adapter.withOnClickListener(new FastAdapter.OnClickListener<Incoming_Request_adapter>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClick(View v, IAdapter<Incoming_Request_adapter> adapter, Incoming_Request_adapter item, int position) {
            Intent otherprofileintent = new Intent(getActivity(), Other_Profile.class);
            otherprofileintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            otherprofileintent.putExtra("frd_status", item.getFriend_status());
            otherprofileintent.putExtra("frd_id", item.getTo_user_id());
            startActivity(otherprofileintent);
            return true;
        }
    });
    incoming_req_adapter.withItemEvent(new ClickEventHook<Incoming_Request_adapter>() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v, int position, FastAdapter<Incoming_Request_adapter> fastAdapter, Incoming_Request_adapter item) {
            acceptrequest(item.getTo_user_id(), position);
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onBind(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
            if (viewHolder instanceof Incoming_Request_adapter.FriendRequest_ViewHolder) {
                return viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.accept);
            }
            return null;
        }
    });
    incoming_req_adapter.withItemEvent(new ClickEventHook<Incoming_Request_adapter>() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v, int position, FastAdapter<Incoming_Request_adapter> fastAdapter, Incoming_Request_adapter item) {
            deleterequest(item.getTo_user_id(), position);
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onBind(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
            if (viewHolder instanceof Incoming_Request_adapter.FriendRequest_ViewHolder) {
                return viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
            }
            return null;
        }
    });
    incoming_req_adapter.withItemEvent(new ClickEventHook<Incoming_Request_adapter>() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v, int position, FastAdapter<Incoming_Request_adapter> fastAdapter, Incoming_Request_adapter item) {
            sendrequest(item.getTo_user_id(), position);
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onBind(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
            if (viewHolder instanceof Incoming_Request_adapter.FriendRequest_ViewHolder) {
                return viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.sendrequest);
            }
            return null;
        }
    });
    /*incoming_refresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            loadrefreshcomplete = 1;
            incoming_req_adapter.clear();
            incoming_requests("");
        }
    });*/


}

private void incoming_requests(String value) {
    if (value.isEmpty()) {
        Constant.showloader(getActivity());
    }
    String outgoing_requesturl = Constant.psurl + "myrequests&userid=" + Session.getUserID(getActivity());
    Constant.l(outgoing_requesturl);
    AndroidNetworking.get(outgoing_requesturl).setOkHttpClient(Constant.okClient()).build().getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                if (response.has("friendrequests")) {
                    JSONArray userlistarray = response.getJSONArray("friendrequests");
                    for (int i = 0; i < userlistarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject frdsarrayobj = userlistarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Incoming_Request_adapter incomingadapter = new Incoming_Request_adapter();
                        Search_Pojo search_pojo = new Search_Pojo();
                        search_pojo.setUserid(frdsarrayobj.getString("userid"));
                        search_pojo.setUsername(frdsarrayobj.getString("username"));
                        search_pojo.setEmail(frdsarrayobj.getString("email"));
                        search_pojo.setPhone(frdsarrayobj.getString("phone"));
                        search_pojo.setCity(frdsarrayobj.getString("city"));
                        search_pojo.setUserstatus(frdsarrayobj.getString("user_status"));
                        search_pojo.setUser_profile_pic(frdsarrayobj.getString("userprofile"));
                        search_pojo.setFriend_status(frdsarrayobj.getString("friend_status"));
                        incomingadapter.setTo_user_id(frdsarrayobj.getString("userid"));
                        incomingadapter.setUsername(frdsarrayobj.getString("username"));
                        incomingadapter.setEmail(frdsarrayobj.getString("email"));
                        incomingadapter.setPhone(frdsarrayobj.getString("phone"));
                        incomingadapter.setCity(frdsarrayobj.getString("city"));
                        incomingadapter.setUserstatus(frdsarrayobj.getString("user_status"));
                        incomingadapter.setUser_profile_pic(frdsarrayobj.getString("userprofile"));
                        incomingadapter.setFriend_status(frdsarrayobj.getString("friend_status"));
                        incoming_req_adapter.add(incomingadapter);
                        searchlist.add(search_pojo);
                    }
                } else {
                    frd_req_no.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    incoming_req_recycler_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                if (response.has("userslist")) {
                    JSONArray frdlistarray = response.getJSONArray("userslist");
                    for (int j = 0; j < frdlistarray.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject userarrayobj = frdlistarray.getJSONObject(j);
                        Search_Pojo search_pojo = new Search_Pojo();
                        search_pojo.setUserid(userarrayobj.getString("userid"));
                        search_pojo.setUsername(userarrayobj.getString("username"));
                        search_pojo.setEmail(userarrayobj.getString("email"));
                        search_pojo.setPhone(userarrayobj.getString("phone"));
                        search_pojo.setCity(userarrayobj.getString("city"));
                        search_pojo.setUserstatus(userarrayobj.getString("user_status"));
                        search_pojo.setUser_profile_pic(userarrayobj.getString("userprofile"));
                        search_pojo.setFriend_status(userarrayobj.getString("friend_status"));
                        People_Request_adapter peoplgreqadapter = new People_Request_adapter();
                        peoplgreqadapter.setTo_user_id(userarrayobj.getString("userid"));
                        peoplgreqadapter.setUsername(userarrayobj.getString("username"));
                        peoplgreqadapter.setEmail(userarrayobj.getString("email"));
                        peoplgreqadapter.setPhone(userarrayobj.getString("phone"));
                        peoplgreqadapter.setCity(userarrayobj.getString("city"));
                        peoplgreqadapter.setUserstatus(userarrayobj.getString("user_status"));
                        peoplgreqadapter.setUser_profile_pic(userarrayobj.getString("userprofile"));
                        peoplgreqadapter.setFriend_status(userarrayobj.getString("friend_status"));
                        people_req_adapter.add(peoplgreqadapter);
                        searchlist.add(search_pojo);
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Constant.l(e.toString());
                Constant.dismissloader();
            }
            if (!value.isEmpty()) {
                Constant.dismissloader();
            }
            /*if (loadrefreshcomplete == 1) {
                loadrefreshcomplete = 0;
                incoming_refresh.setRefreshing(false);
                Constant.dismissloader();
            }*/
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(ANError anError) {
            Constant.l(anError.toString());
            Constant.dismissloader();
        }
    });
}


public void acceptrequest(String fid, final int position) {
    Constant.showloader(getActivity());
    String sendurl = Constant.psurl + "sendrequest&from_id=" + fid + "&to_id=" + Session.getUserID(getActivity());
    Constant.l(sendurl);
    AndroidNetworking.get(sendurl).build().getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                if (response.getString("status").equals("Success")) {
                    incoming_req_adapter.remove(position);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Constant.l(e.toString());
                Constant.dismissloader();
            }
            Constant.dismissloader();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(ANError anError) {
            Constant.l(anError.toString());
            Constant.dismissloader();
        }
    });
}

public void deleterequest(String fid, final int position) {
    Constant.showloader(getActivity());
    String sendurl = Constant.psurl + "deleterequest&from_id=" + Session.getUserID(getActivity()) + "&to_id=" + fid;
    Constant.l(sendurl);
    AndroidNetworking.get(sendurl).build().getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                if (response.getString("status").equals("Success")) {
                    incoming_req_adapter.remove(position);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Constant.l(e.toString());
                Constant.dismissloader();
            }
            Constant.dismissloader();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(ANError anError) {
            Constant.l(anError.toString());
            Constant.dismissloader();
        }
    });
}

public void sendrequest(String fid, final int position) {
    Constant.showloader(getActivity());
    String sendurl = Constant.psurl + "sendrequest&from_id=" + Session.getUserID(getActivity()) + "&to_id=" + fid;
    Constant.l(sendurl);
    AndroidNetworking.get(sendurl).build().getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                if (response.getString("status").equals("Success")) {
                    incoming_req_adapter.remove(position);
                    EventBus.getDefault().post(new Event_Bus("outgoing"));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Constant.l(e.toString());
                Constant.dismissloader();
            }
            Constant.dismissloader();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(ANError anError) {
            Constant.l(anError.toString());
            Constant.dismissloader();
        }
    });
}

@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void groupcreated(Event_Bus eventBus) {
    if (eventBus.getEventname().equals("incoming")) {
        incoming_req_adapter.clear();
        incoming_requests("incoming");
        Constant.dismissloader();
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    super.onStop();
}
```

}

Adapter.class

```
public class Incoming_Request_adapter extends AbstractItem<Incoming_Request_adapter, Incoming_Request_adapter.FriendRequest_ViewHolder> {
    @SerializedName("userid")
    private String to_user_id;
    @SerializedName("userprofile")
    private String user_profile_pic;
    @SerializedName("username")
    private String username;
    @SerializedName("email")
    private String email;
    @SerializedName("phone")
    private String phone;
    @SerializedName("city")
    private String city;
    @SerializedName("user_status")
    private String userstatus;
    @SerializedName("friend_status")
    private String friend_status;


    public String getFriend_status() {
        return friend_status;
    }

    public void setFriend_status(String friend_status) {
        this.friend_status = friend_status;
    }

    public String getTo_user_id() {
        return to_user_id;
    }

    public void setTo_user_id(String to_user_id) {
        this.to_user_id = to_user_id;
    }

    public String getUser_profile_pic() {
        return user_profile_pic;
    }

    public void setUser_profile_pic(String user_profile_pic) {
        this.user_profile_pic = user_profile_pic;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getUserstatus() {
        return userstatus;
    }

    public void setUserstatus(String userstatus) {
        this.userstatus = userstatus;
    }

    @Override
    public int getType() {
        return R.id.incoming_req_recycler_view;
    }


    @Override
    public int getLayoutRes() {
        return R.layout.incoming_request_item;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(FriendRequest_ViewHolder holder, List<Object> payloads) {
        super.bindView(holder, payloads);
        holder.frd_req_item_name.setText(username.replace("$", " "));
        holder.frd_req_msg.setText(userstatus.replace("$", " "));
        Picasso.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(user_profile_pic).into(holder.frd_req_img);
        if (friend_status.equals("1")) {
            holder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.sendrequest.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else if (friend_status.equals("0")) {
            holder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.sendrequest.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }


    }


    public static class FriendRequest_ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.frd_req_img)
        CircleImageView frd_req_img;
        @BindView(R.id.frd_req_item_name)
        TextView frd_req_item_name;
        @BindView(R.id.frd_req_msg)
        TextView frd_req_msg;
        @BindView(R.id.accept)
        FancyButton accept;
        @BindView(R.id.cancel)
        FancyButton cancel;
        @BindView(R.id.linearLayout)
        LinearLayout linearLayout;
        @BindView(R.id.sendrequest)
        FancyButton sendrequest;
        @BindView(R.id.incoming_text)
        AppCompatTextView incoming_text;


        public FriendRequest_ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is onCreateViewHolder method in adapter class?

Comment: I am using the Fast adapter of mikepenz we dont need that method in this library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell you are using an outdated version of the `FastAdapter` which still had a feature enabled, to automatically detect the provided `ViewHolder`. As this functionality sometimes lead to the above error message (if used with proguard) it was removed in a newer version and replaced by a simple `getViewHolder` method.

```
@Override
public ViewHolder getViewHolder(View v) {
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}
```

This new approach was introduced with the `FastAdapter` v2.5.0: https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter/blob/develop/MIGRATION.md#v250

For older versions of the `FastAdapter`, there was the concept of a `ViewHolderFactory` which would (as an alternative to the automatic detection, which is not working in your case) provide the `ViewHolder` to the `FastAdapter`

Basically you'd implement the `ViewHolderFactory` and define the `ViewHolderFactory` in your item.

```
private static final ViewHolderFactory<? extends ViewHolder> FACTORY = new ItemFactory();
```

In addition you'd need the following:

```
/**
 * our ItemFactory implementation which creates the ViewHolder for our adapter.
 * It is highly recommended to implement a ViewHolderFactory as it is 0-1ms faster for ViewHolder creation,
 * and it is also many many times more efficient if you define custom listeners on views within your item.
 */
protected static class ItemFactory implements ViewHolderFactory<ViewHolder> {
    public ViewHolder create(View v) {
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }
}

/**
 * return our ViewHolderFactory implementation here
 *
 * @return
 */
@Override
public ViewHolderFactory<? extends ViewHolder> getFactory() {
    return FACTORY;
}
```

You can see the whole thing here:
https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter/blob/v2.2.0/app/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/fastadapter/app/items/IconItem.java#L24

As an alternative adjusting the proguard rules could also work.

My recommendation is to update to one of the latest `FastAdapter` releases, as this was greatly simplified and enhanced.